# UITableView tableFooterView shows at the top of the UITableView - wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, tablefooterview

I have created a very simple test case to reproduce this issue.

I am trying to set a footer view programmatically to a tableview. Please note that I am referring to the footer at the very bottom of the tableview - NOT the section footer (most stack overflow answers confuse them).

Here's my very simple code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *footerContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    footerContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    footerContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [footerContainer addConstraints:@[[NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:footerContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:100
                                       ],
                                      [NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:footerContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
                                       ]]];

    self.mytableview.tableFooterView=footerContainer;
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

However, the outcome looks like this:

[image]

As you notice, the footer shows on top of the tableview. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

If I change the tableFooterView to tableHeaderView, then it works fine. So I was expecting the same to work for footer too but it doesn't.

Comment: Setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` is likely breaking whatever method the tableview uses to position the footer.

Comment: Are you using constraints because you will (or may) have dynamic content in the footer view? If so, I can give you a solution for that...

Comment: @DonMag yes I was looking for a solution which will use constraints to set it up instead of setting the frame manually. My actual app has dynamic sized content for the footer.

Answer (score 44):

**Do not set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`** on a `UIView` being assigned to `tableView.tableFooterView`.

In your case, this is `footerContainer`. I had this same problem. It was mentioned in a comment on the question, but I still spent hours troubleshooting before I noticed I was doing that, so I am putting it here as a possible answer as well.

Comment: Seconding this.

Comment: This so much this!

Answer (score 6):

I have tried the same with explicit frame values in swift and I achieved the behaviour as you asked for, Try it with the explicit frame value if you think its fine. And remove the layout constraints if its not needed.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell!
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: that does work for me yes. Does it mean auto layout is buggy with footer view? Should I log it as a bug with Apple?

Comment: @PranoyC : Happy it solved your issue, And sorry I don't have style of using manual auto layout code and can't help you with direct answer for your bug report idea, But I would suggest if you are about to raise an issue, raise after you try setting the auto layout for simple view in a view controller.

Comment: This issue can be solved by using a container view. See my answer below.

Comment: Your answer helped me by setting me in the right direction. I fixed it with using just the old friend autoresizing mask, the second I put even a constraint on my label, chaos unleashed. Definitely, an Apple bug right there.

Comment: try a smaller device and you'll see how it looks. Wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic-sized `UITableView` Header and Footer views do not always play nice with auto-layout, so you need to give it a little help.

Here is an example that creates a simple `UIView` for the footer view and adds an "expanding" `UILabel` (number of lines set to Zero). The footer view is created with an explicit CGRect for its frame, and the label is pinned to all four sides with auto-layout constraints.

In `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, we tell auto-layout to calculate the frame of the footer view, based on the constraints on its contents, and then we update the frame values (well, specifically the height).

```
//
// this assumes IBOutlet has been set for "theTableView"
//

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // standard stuff
    [_theTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"simpleCell"];
    _theTableView.delegate = self;
    _theTableView.dataSource = self;

    // instantiate a view for the table footer
    // width doesn't matter (it will be stretched to fit the table by default)
    // set height to a big number to avoid a "will attempt to break constraint" warning
    UIView *footerContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1000)];

    // give it a color so we can see it
    footerContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    // set the footer view
    _theTableView.tableFooterView = footerContainer;


    // instantiate a label to add to the footer view
    UILabel *aLabel = [UILabel new];

    // auto-sizing the height, so set lines to zero
    aLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    // give it a color so we can see it
    aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    // set the text to 8 lines for demonstration purposes
    aLabel.text = @"Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5\nLine 6\nLine 7\nLine 8";

    // standard, for auto-sizing
    aLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // add the label to the footer view
    [footerContainer addSubview:aLabel];

    // constraint the label to 8-pts from each edge...
    [aLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:footerContainer.topAnchor constant:8.0].active = YES;
    [aLabel.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:footerContainer.leftAnchor constant:8.0].active = YES;
    [aLabel.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:footerContainer.rightAnchor constant:-8.0].active = YES;
    [aLabel.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:footerContainer.bottomAnchor constant:-8.0].active = YES;

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // get a reference to the table's footer view
    UIView *currentFooterView = [_theTableView tableFooterView];

    // if it's a valid reference (the table *does* have a footer view)
    if (currentFooterView) {

        // tell auto-layout to calculate the size based on the footer view's content
        CGFloat newHeight = [currentFooterView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

        // get the current frame of the footer view
        CGRect currentFrame = currentFooterView.frame;

        // we only want to do this when necessary (otherwise we risk infinite recursion)
        // so... if the calculated height is not the same as the current height
        if (newHeight != currentFrame.size.height) {
            // use the new (calculated) height
            currentFrame.size.height = newHeight;
            currentFooterView.frame = currentFrame;
        }

    }

}
```

This can also be helpful when trying to get auto-sizing table view header views to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Autolayout` and `Xibs` to create a footer view. But you have to put your custom view to the container view, that you assign to `tableFooterView`.

```
func setupTableFooterView() {
    // Create your footer view from XIB and set constraints (in my case it is historyToolBarView of class HistoryToolBarView)
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HistoryToolBarView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first
    historyToolBarView = view as! HistoryToolBarView
    historyToolBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    historyToolBarView.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self.historyToolBarView,
                                 attribute: .height,
                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                 toItem: nil,
                                 attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                 constant: 60),
         NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: self.historyToolBarView,
                                 attribute: .width,
                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                 toItem: nil,
                                 attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                 constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)])

    // Create a container of your footer view called footerView and set it as a tableFooterView
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 60))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView

    // Add your footer view to the container
    footerView.addSubview(historyToolBarView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table view is ignoring the constraints.
Set the `height` manually and it'll work:

```swift
tableView.tableFooterView?.frame.size.height = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

set grouped style for table and set height for header CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude

```
tableView.style = .grouped

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```