# how do I have a tableview footer whose height auto increases

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout, table-footer

I would like to add a label to table footer which will auto increase and footer height also auto increases .How can I achieve this any ideas

Comment: This was in answer to another issue, but it solves the table footer auto-sizing as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414131/6257435

Comment: Please show the code you've written and we can help you see where you're going wrong. To encourage people to help you, you show that you've _tried_ to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to calculate the height of text in the UILabel.

```
let messageTextSize = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: dialogViewWidth, height:  CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
```

and then you set label frame to have height / width correspond to text

```
let textLabel = UILabel()
textLabel.frame = CGRect.init(x: sidePadding, y: titleLabel.frame.origin.y + titleLabel.frame.size.height, width: dialogViewWidth - 2 * sidePadding, height:messageTextSize.height)
```

you would usually do in view's `layoutSubview`